# Calling undefined copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

This is my class hierarchy.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class baseClass
{
public:
    int var;
    int* varPtr;

    baseClass(int value) : var(value), varPtr(&var)
    {
        cout << "baseClass constructor" << endl;
    }
};

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
public:
    derivedClass(int value) : baseClass(value)
    {
        cout << "derivedClass constructor" << endl;
    }

    derivedClass(const derivedClass& objToCopy)
    {
        cout << "derivedClass copy constructor" << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    derivedClass derivedObj1(5);
    derivedClass derivedObj2(derivedObj1);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me a no default constructor error. Which is correct as I don't have a default constructor defined. Now my question is when I call the copy constructor of baseClass from derivedClass.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class baseClass
{
public:
    int var;
    int* varPtr;

    baseClass(int value) : var(value), varPtr(&var)
    {
        cout << "baseClass constructor" << endl;
    }
};

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
public:
    derivedClass(int value) : baseClass(value)
    {
        cout << "derivedClass constructor" << endl;
    }

    derivedClass(const derivedClass& objToCopy) : baseClass(objToCopy) // <- ADDED
    {
        cout << "derivedClass copy constructor" << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    derivedClass derivedObj1(5);
    derivedClass derivedObj2(derivedObj1);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I get no error although I have not defined a copy constructor. There is no constructor that takes a reference of baseClass. Why isn't the compiler not complaining? Why is it happy to just do  bitwise copy when I'm explicitly calling for the copy constructor? Why there is no error saying that baseClass(const baseClass&) undefined?

Thank you.

Comment: `baseClass(const baseClass&)` is provided to you by the compiler.

Comment: "If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as an inline public member of its class." ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor))

Comment: Thank you. Then my question is why didn't the compiler provide a copy constructor in the first program? When I didn't explicitly call the baseClass copy constructor? Why in that case I got a no default constructor error?

Comment: Because a default constructor is not a copy constructor, so different rules apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy-constructors are implicitly added to the class if you do not provide one. In order to prevent copying of your class, you can `delete` the compiler-generated one, like so:

```
baseClass(const baseClass& objToCopy) =delete;
```

The compiler errors in the first program because it attempts to call a no-argument constructor instead of a copy constructor to construct the base-class part of the object. Since you have already defined a custom constructor for the class, the default no-argument version is not implicitly generated.

Comment: Thank you. I understand copy constructors are added by the compiler if it is not defined. The question I have is then why the compiler didn't generate one in the first program.

Comment: @madu: It did, it just didn't try to call it.

Comment: @Puppy Thank you. So let me summarize. In the first case, copy constructor is generated, but the compiler is NOT trying to call it. It is trying to call a default constructor. In the second case, when I explicitly call the copy constructor, it calls the generated one. Case two makes sense to me. But is there a particular reason why the compiler try to call default constructor and NOT the copy constructor in the first case?

Comment: @madu that is correct. The copy constructor is not called because the compiler will *always* attempt to generate a call to the no-argument base class constructor unless otherwise advised.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to know. The behavior of the compiler in this case.

Comment: @madu, when you wrote a user-defined copy constructor the compiler assumes you know what you're doing, so when you wrote it without anything like `baseClass(objToCopy)` in the ctor-initializer-list it tells the compiler you do not want to pass any arguments to the base class constructor. If you do want to pass arguments to the base class constructor then you either need to do that by hand, or let the compiler generate the _entire_ constructor. It will not generate a call to a base copy constructor in a function that you have written, only in functions it generates itself.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you. That explanation makes sense as to why compiler invokes the default constructor when nothing is explicitly called.

Answer (score 0):

In derived class the copy constructor is defined that way :

```
derivedClass(const derivedClass& objToCopy)
{
    cout << "derivedClass copy constructor" << endl;
}
```

By default, the copy constructor of a derived class uses the copy constructor of base class but you were explicitely declaring a copy constructor without specifying how you wanted to construct the base class object, so the compiler tried to use the default constructor.

You should write :

```
derivedClass(const derivedClass& objToCopy): baseClass(objToCopy.value)
{
    cout << "derivedClass copy constructor" << endl;
}
```

to correctly use the explicit base constructor.

Comment: This answer seems good except for this sentence, which I don't understand: _"Some recent compilers seem to be able to use the copy constructor of base class but in your case it is not declared either."_ Also your example should use `baseClass(objToCopy)` not `baseClass(objToCopy.value)` to copy the base sub-object.

Comment: For first part, you are right : copy ctor in derived class calls copy ctor of base class - I'v edited my post. For second part, I wanted to use the explicit ctor `baseClass(int i)`, because I prefere explicit things.

Answer (score -1):

I believe, the reason for this behavior has to do with [constructor delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement) since C++11.

Comment: There are no delegating constructors in the example, and the behaviour is the same pre-C++11